# Wrong output of ActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, activity-manager

I'm trying to check if the specific process is running by using `getRunningAppProcesses` inside of `BroadcastReceiver.onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)`. But when that specific application is completely closed method `getRunningAppProcesses` tells me that it's running and have foreground importance (`proc.importance == 100`). How is it can be? Is it i'm getting an old context?

Comment: What does "completely closed" mean?

Comment: It means that i swipe away the app from running apps an i see the home screen.

Comment: Perhaps it has a foreground service.

Comment: It's might be. But then when main app is actually running too there should be 2 processes with same - the service and the app itself.